# How to upload an image from telegram bot into users's own twiter account?

Tags: twitter-api-v2

Hello guys I need help !

I'm working on a Telegram bot that generates images, and I want users to be able to share these images on their Twitter accounts. I've successfully uploaded the image to Twitter and obtained the media_id, but I'm struggling to figure out how to attach this image to a tweet using Twitter Web Intents.

I've referred to the Twitter Web Intents documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents), but I couldn't find a clear example or explanation on how to include media in the tweet using Web Intents.
Could someone provide guidance or a code example on how to use Twitter Web Intents to attach an image to a tweet programmatically?

so far I send image to twtter server and got media_id , I cannot send the media_id in web intent , i can send only text not media

- Send media to twitter and get media_id

```
onst tweet = async () => {
    const uri = "https://i.imgur.com/Zl2GLjnh.jpg";
    const filename = "image.png";

    download(uri, filename, async function () {
      try {
        const mediaId = await twitterClient.v1.uploadMedia("./image.png");
        console.log(mediaId);
        await twitterClient.v2.tweet({
          text: "Hello world! This is an image in Ukraine!",
          media: {
            media_ids: [mediaId],
          },
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
  };

  tweet();
```

Share the image on user own twitter  when they press share button

```
export const twitterShareKeyboard = {
  reply_markup: {
    inline_keyboard: [
      [
        {
          text: "Share it on X",
          url: "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=This meme is generated using memeProof, unleash your creativity using https://t.me/MemeProfBot",
        },
      ],
    ],
    remove_keyboard: true,
  },
};
```